# Override AppendText

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, user-controls

I made my own custom TextBox control, but now I need to add the AppendText property, does anyone have any idea how to do this? I can't seem to find any information about this on Google, I can only find how you use it, not how you implant it in a custom control.

Here is the code of the TextBox if anyone is interested http://pastebin.com/iW4xQCai.

Comment: I guess the obvious question would be why aren't you inheriting from `TextBox`?

Comment: Because then I think I can't give it custom colors. Or can I?

Comment: @FoxyShadoww What do you mean "can't give it custom colours"?

Comment: Yes, you can. `BackColor = Color.Red`.

Comment: Well, you see I want to give it custom colors like a dark border and dark background so it fits the theme of my application.

Comment: Please consider reading some basic literature about programming with C# and its UI-technologies, like WPF or WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you would be much better off inheriting directly from `TextBox` instead of creating a composite control.

Either way, there should be no problem implementing the `AppendText` **method** ([there is a difference between a method and a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wwfsses%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

If you are not overriding `TextBox`, simply add a new method to your class which passes the call to your textbox.

```
public void AppendText(string txt)
{
    textBox.AppendText(txt);
}
```

If you *are* overriding `TextBox`, this would require absolutely no code as the method would already be inherited.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the method and property,   EDIT: I will try this code as well. I think I'll inherit from RichTextBox.